# Showing that a function is proper...

Tags: general-topology, matrices

I'm a little stuck with a problem.
I have to prove that a function is proper.

The said function, named $\psi$ is the one that goes from $M_{n-k,k}(\mathbb{R})$ to $M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$ and is defined by $\psi(M)=\varphi(\begin{pmatrix}I \\M\end{pmatrix})$, where $\varphi$ is the function from the set of matrix of $M_{n,k}(\mathbb{R})$ which rank is k to $M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\varphi(A)=A((^tAA)^{-1})^{t}A$.

After some calculus, I've come to the following result :
$\psi(M)=\begin{pmatrix}Q(M)&Q(M)^tM\\MQ(M)&MQ(M)^tM\end{pmatrix}$ where $Q(M)=(I+^tMM)^{-1}$. I've also shown that $\psi$ is a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ immersion and is injective.

But now I don't see how I can prove that $\psi$ is proper ; besides, whith $n=2$ and $k=1$ with $M_j=(j)$ for $j\in\mathbb{N}$, the norm of the $M_j$ will tend towards $\infty$ when $j\rightarrow\infty$ whereas $\psi(M_j)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{1+j^2}&\frac{j}{1+j^2}\\\frac{j}{1+j^2}&\frac{j^2}{1+j^2}\end{pmatrix}$ doesn't tend towards $\infty$ in norm... So $\psi$ shouldn't be proper, and that exemple can easily expand to arbitraries $n$ and $k$ in $\mathbb{N}$.

Any ideas on that matter ? Did something went wrong with my computation ? Thanks in advance (and sorry for my broken english btw, it's not my native language).

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is right. Anyone who is familiar with [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) should know that $A(AA^T)^{-1}A^T$ is an orthogonal projector. It follows that the norm of $\psi(M)$ is bounded (in fact, if the operator 2-norm is used, we always have $\|\psi(M)\|_2=1$ for every $M$). Since $M_{n-k,k}(\mathbb R)$ is not even a bounded set, $\psi$ is not a proper map.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, there must be a problem with the text then... I've e-mailed my teacher about that.